# Prevent inline-block from wrapping on white-space: pre?

Tags: word-wrap, css

It seems Chrome is wrapping an inline-block element if it is at the end of a line even if there is a white-space:pre container around it with overflow: auto. Is there a workable solution to prevent this from happening without changing the content?

```
<div style="width:400px;height:200px;overflow:auto;white-space:pre">
The span should be at the end of this text, however, it wraps to the next line.<span style="width:1px;display:inline-block;height:1em;background:red"></span>
</div>
```

The white-space must be preserved using newlines at least. Spaces and tabs may be compressed.

Comment: did you ever find a solution or work around for this problem? I have the same issue in Chrome: needing to preserve white-space and prevent wrapping.

Comment: I also have this problem. Is this a bug in Chrome?

Answer (score 7):

This bug is [4 years old](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35443) and still present in the latest Chrome and Safari, but I did find a workaround that doesn't add undesirable whitespace, which is to add an empty `:after` pseudo-element: http://jsbin.com/oQuBAmIJ/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your white-space setting to `white-space: nowrap` instead.

Comment: This does prevent the span from wrapping, however it takes away the whitespace preservation used by the white-space: pre.

Comment: Would it work to change the white-space setting in your div style and to wrap the inner text with a <pre> tag?